# How to check if the MQTT connection is still active?

Tags: gsm, mqtt, mkr-gsm-1400

I am wondering if there is a way to check and see if the MQTT connection is still active.

The reason for this is that I am having trouble with the connection dropping after a short while and not seeming to reconnect.

```cpp
/*
  ArduinoMqttClient - WiFi Simple Sender

  This example connects to a MQTT broker and publishes a message to
  a topic once a second.

  The circuit:
  - Arduino MKR 1000, MKR 1010 or Uno WiFi Rev2 board

  This example code is in the public domain.
*/

#include <ArduinoMqttClient.h>
#include <MKRGSM.h>

#include "arduino_secrets.h"
// Please enter your sensitive data in the Secret tab or arduino_secrets.h
// PIN Number
const char PINNUMBER[]     = SECRET_PINNUMBER;
// APN data
const char GPRS_APN[]      = SECRET_GPRS_APN;
const char GPRS_LOGIN[]    = SECRET_GPRS_LOGIN;
const char GPRS_PASSWORD[] = SECRET_GPRS_PASSWORD;

GSMClient client;
GPRS gprs;
GSM gsmAccess;
MqttClient mqttClient(client);

const char broker[] = "*****";
int        port     = 1883;
const char topic[]  = "Tempdata";

const long interval = 500000;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;

float SERIESRESISTOR = 9.87;
float TEMPERATURENOMINAL = 25.0;
float BCOEFFICIENT = 3540.0;
float thermistor = 0.0;
float THERMISTORNOMINAL = 10;

int count = 0;

void setup() {
  // Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("Starting Arduino web client.");
  // connection state
  bool connected = false;

  // After starting the modem with GSM.begin()
  // attach the shield to the GPRS network with the APN, login and password
  while (!connected) {
    if ((gsmAccess.begin(PINNUMBER) == GSM_READY) &&
        (gprs.attachGPRS(GPRS_APN, GPRS_LOGIN, GPRS_PASSWORD) == GPRS_READY)) {
      connected = true;
    } else {
      Serial.println("Not connected");
      delay(1000);
    }
  }

  Serial.println("You're connected to the network");
  Serial.println();

  // You can provide a unique client ID, if not set the library uses Arduino-millis()
  // Each client must have a unique client ID
  mqttClient.setId("pump-house-gsm");

  // You can provide a username and password for authentication
  //mqttClient.setUsernamePassword("****", "****");

  Serial.print("Attempting to connect to the MQTT broker: ");
  Serial.println(broker);

  if (!mqttClient.connect(broker, port)) {
    Serial.print("MQTT connection failed! Error code = ");
    Serial.println(mqttClient.connectError());

    while (1);
  }

  Serial.println("You're connected to the MQTT broker!");
  Serial.println();

  // set analog resulotion to 12
  analogReadResolution(12);
}

void loop() {
  // call poll() regularly to allow the library to send MQTT keep alives which
  // avoids being disconnected by the broker
  mqttClient.poll();

  // to avoid having delays in loop, we'll use the strategy from BlinkWithoutDelay
  // see: File -> Examples -> 02.Digital -> BlinkWithoutDelay for more info
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    /*Read analog outputof NTC module,
     i.e the voltage across the thermistor */
    float average = ((float)analogRead(A0) / 4095.0) * 3.3;

    average = (average * SERIESRESISTOR) / (3.3 - average);

    float steinhart;
    steinhart = average / THERMISTORNOMINAL;     // (R/Ro)
    steinhart = log(steinhart);                  // ln(R/Ro)
    steinhart /= BCOEFFICIENT;                   // 1/B * ln(R/Ro)
    steinhart += 1.0 / (TEMPERATURENOMINAL + 273.15); // + (1/To)
    steinhart = 1.0 / steinhart;                 // Invert
    steinhart -= 273.15;                         // convert absolute temp to C

    // save the last time a message was sent
    previousMillis = currentMillis;

    // Keep track of times a message was sent
    // this is to reconnect every hour.
    count = count + 1;

    // send message, the Print interface can be used to set the message contents
    mqttClient.beginMessage(topic);
    mqttClient.print("The temperature is ");
    mqttClient.print(steinhart);
    mqttClient.endMessage();
  }
}
```

Maybe `endMessage`, `beginMessage`, or `poll` has a return that says it has failed to send a message?

I've looked at `endMessage` and `beginMessage` and it does not seem like it to me, but `poll` is much more complicated and I can't really tell.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution with the `connected` function included in the ArduinoMqttClient (found it browsing the library code).

Here is a code snippet showing what I added:

```cpp
...
...
if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
  if (!mqttClient.connected()) {
    if (mqttClient.connect(broker, port)) {
        Serial.println("reconnected");
    }
  }

  /*Read analog outputof NTC module,
  i.e the voltage across the thermistor */
  float average = ((float)analogRead(A0) / 4095.0) * 3.3;
...
...
```

It is working so far!